# What is the corresponding study about the effects of growing up without a mother?

Tags: developmental-psychology, parenting

We know that deprivation of a father affects development of children - and leads to them being angrier and more depressed as an adult:

> ‘This is the first time research findings have shown that paternal deprivation during development affects the neurobiology of the offspring.’ ([Spencer, 2013](http://www.dailymail.co.uk/sciencetech/article-2518247/Growing-father-permanently-alter-BRAIN-Fatherless-children-likely-grow-angry-turn-drugs.html))

The research article this was based on was:

> Bambico, F. R., Lacoste, B., Hattan, P. R., & Gobbi, G. (2013). Father absence in the monogamous California mouse impairs social behavior and modifies dopamine and glutamate synapses in the medial prefrontal cortex. Cerebral Cortex, 25(5), 1163-1175.
>   DOI: [10.1093/cercor/bht310](https://doi.org/10.1093/cercor/bht310)

So there must be a corresponding study of development changes without a mother. What are the corresponding effects?

My question is: **What is the corresponding study about the effects of growing up without a mother?**

Comment: related: https://psychology.stackexchange.com/q/19263/7604